# Copy lines between two specific strings using Python when subprocess is involved

Tags: python, subprocess

I  want to append specific lines of code (code between two specific lines) from file1.v into file2.sv

I'm trying to run external perl script from python with the help of subprocess module. This external perl script creates "file2.sv" for me. file1.v is already in existence.

My issue is file2.sv is created by perl script successfully however code I'm trying to append lines to file2.sv from file1.v is not working

Here is the code:

```
pipe = subprocess.Popen(
    ["Verilog.pl", "file1.v", "file2.sv", "0", "SystemVerilog", "SV","0"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

with open("file1.v","r") as rf_VamsModel, open("file2.sv", "a") as wf_sytemVerilogFile:
    copy = False
    for line in rf_VamsModel:
        if line.strip() == "//Start of functional specification here":
            copy = True
        elif line.strip() == "//End of functional specification here":
            copy = False
        elif copy:
            print("line test2={}".format(line))
            wf_sytemVerilogFile.write(line)
```

Is it because subprocess.Popen and file append processes are executing in parallel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Popen` constructor starts a process, but it doesn't wait for it to finish before returning.  It's likely that you're trying to read and write to the two files before the perl script is finished writing to them.

You can wait for the perl script to finish by calling `wait()`

```
process = subprocess.Popen(...)
process.wait()
```